# CSV with EPPlus parsing issues

Tags: c#, excel, csv, epplus

I am using EPPlus to read data.
This data consists of either a `.xlsx` or `.csv`.

When the file is a `.csv` file I use the `LoadFromText` functionality.
But EPPlus decides that it also has to parse all the values, which it **shouldn't**.

For instance:

```
Id;Double;
1;-3,88;

ExcelTextFormat format = new ExcelTextFormat();
format.Delimiter = ';';
worksheet.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromText( "file", format );
```

Result is that the `-3,88` value becomes: `-388` in the worksheet. This i found out is because EPPlus sees the -3,88 as a number and parses it as a number with the default culture being `InvariantCulture` which in this case is (similar to) `us-US`.

How can i achieve that EPPlus loads the csv without parsing? (takes all values as strings)

Comment: You just need to set the culture to something more "local".  See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927002/epplus-converting-csv-and-missing-the-comma-from-a-double/36938148#36938148

Comment: Then I will get the format that i need for that culture yes, but i need the string since it is used for multiple cultures in the code base.

Comment: Try to set the column format to text before importing: `worksheet.Cells["A:A"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that EPPlus always parses imported data with the `en-US` format. So first import the column with the decimal values as a string. That way there is no attempt at conversion.

```
ExcelTextFormat format = new ExcelTextFormat
{
    Delimiter = ';',
    DataTypes = new eDataTypes[] { eDataTypes.Number, eDataTypes.String }
};
```

And after the values are imported with the correct decimal separators for your localization, loop the values, convert them to decimal and set the correct number format.

```
int columnNumber = 2;

for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    worksheet.Cells[i, columnNumber].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
    worksheet.Cells[i, columnNumber].Value = Convert.ToDecimal(worksheet.Cells[i, columnNumber].Value);
}
```

Comment: This works, how ever I do not know up front how many columns a document will have, its not always the second column to have a number. Can I set the eDataTypes.String for the entire document?

Comment: No, it has to be per column if you use `ExcelTextFormat`, but you can just add 20 `eDataTypes.String` so the first 20 columns will be a string, even if they don't exist in the CSV. But if you don't know the correct columns then performing a conversion will also prove difficult unless ALL columns are numeric/integers.

Comment: I use: eDataTypes[] dataTypes = Enumerable.Repeat(eDataTypes.String, 5000).ToArray(); to make the first 5000 columns String. It aint pretty but it will do for now, thanks!

Comment: @PatrickAleman If the files you are parsing are large it may be worth simply parsing the CSV yourself.  The `LoadFromText` is convenient but adds overheard as do most of the EPPlus `LoadFrom*` methods since they have to be generic for multiple scenarios.  I have actually shaved minutes of import processes by creating my own methods that have only the bare minimum.  And since you want everything as string it would probably be even more dramatic since you avoid all type check logic.

Comment: I totally agree with you. How ever as of this moment it is expected of me to use EPPLus. Personally i would have used something like https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/ for the CSV files.